# Close MVC3 app loaded in modeless dialog after submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a situation where I have an MVC3 application that is being loaded in a modeless dialog (showModelessDialog(url, args, params)).  After I submit the form loaded in the application, I would like to close the modeless dialog box from the mvc controller.  Does anyone know of a way to do this?

So far I have found and tried the following

- returning Javascript("window.close()") from my controller this opens and closes
  a new window.
- returning View("Close") where a Close.cshtml view with
  window.close() called onbody onload, this also opens and closes a new
  window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `showModelessDialog` defined?

Comment: Not sure if you mean where is it called in the other launching application or where is it defined in javascript.  It is available in IE to launch a window that is tied to the parent (I think it is IE only).  It is being called in an external app that needs to occasionally allow a user to create data in mine.  I have some control over how it is called but that is all.